# Recovering from an invalid GOTO command in a Windows batch file

Tags: batch-file

In a Windows batch file, I am taking an optional parameter that allows the caller to jump to the middle of the batch file and resume from there.

For example:

```
if [%1] neq [] (
echo Starting from step %1
goto %1
if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto error
)

:step1

:step2

...

goto end
:error
echo Error handler
...

:end
```

If the supplied parameter is not a valid label, the batch file immediately exits with the error *The system cannot find the batch label specified*.

Is there any way for me to handle this error and either execute my error handler block, or resume execution of the entire batch file, as if no parameter had been supplied?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try using findstr on the batch locating the goto target:

```
findstr /r /i /c:"^:%1" %0>nul
if errorlevel 1 goto error
```

It's a bit of a hack, but should work.

Comment: self-parsing batch files! neat.

Comment: Coding With Style: If the batch file's name includes spaces, then `%0` already contains quotes (otherwise you couldn't have run the batch in the first place). With `%~0` you're just stripping the quotes and re-adding them.

Comment: Huh, learn something new every day. That's completely nonstandard behavior, but I can see why they did that.

Comment: Actually, the label doesn't have to start at the beginning of the line. It can be preceded by any number of `<space>` `<tab>` `,` `;` or `=` characters, although I've only ever used spaces. So safer to use `findstr /r /i /c:"^[<space>]*:%1" %0>nul`. Or to be really complete, use `findstr /r /i /c:"^[<space><tab>,;=]*:%1" %0>nul`.

Comment: It's a clever trick, but this seems like one of those solutions where script performance will degrade really quickly as the script gets longer and you call it more, so I'd prefer the `call :label` alternative.

Comment: @Tydaeus: I believe that if performance of the batch language is a problem, then you already have bigger ones ...

Answer (score 5):

`call :label` <s>spits out the error</s> doesn't spit out an error when stderr is redirected (thanks, Johannes), and doesn't appear to change the error level, but continues with the batch file. You could set a variable after a label to indicate whether execution got that far.

```
@echo off
call :foo 2>nul
echo %errorlevel%
:bar
echo bar
```

yields

```
C:\>test.cmd
The system cannot find the batch label specified - foo
1
bar
C:\>
```

Comment: You can use 2>nul after the call to suppress the error message output.

Comment: Per https://ss64.com/nt/call.html, Windows 7 testing, and your sample output, it looks like the failed call does set `ERRORLEVEL` to 1. This means that if you're using `call` on a subroutine that returns a status code with `exit /b` (instead of using it as a goto), you'll need to figure out whether your `ERRORLEVEL` 1 is because of a missing label or because of an error reported by the subroutine.

One way to solve this would be to have each subroutine set a var (e.g. `FOUND`) to indicate that the label was actually found.

Answer (score 2):

```
goto :label || (
  echo my error handler
)
```

Comment: That's nice answer. You must want put inside a sub in order to get control back.

Answer (score 1):

I probably would do it like this.

```
ECHO Starting from %1
IF "%1" == "step1" GOTO :step1 
IF "%1" == "step2" GOTO :step2
IF "%1" == "step3" GOTO :step3
IF "%1" == "step4" GOTO :step4
ECHO %1 is not valid label name
```

Answer (score -2):

I don't think that Windows batch files support any error handling (except `if errorlevel...`). You will need to validate the passed value is a valid label before the `goto`.

If at all possible I would recommend using PowerShell which is a far richer language and includes exception based error handling.